# Stripe Checkout Implementation does not work

Tags: stripe-payments

I have Stripe Checkout implemented on my website and the Popup-form works.
But it does not register on my Stripe Dashboard; the form submitts and gives me the green success checkmark but nothing gets registered on the Dashboard.
I have set the TEST API key correctly. Why does this not work?
I put it here to test: https://jsfiddle.net/9ofa50j6/

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_dkznH9O1lB7GQDnWeQay8BXS00gPp9FFxC',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
    $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $("#amountInCents").val(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100));
    $("#myForm").submit();
  }
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  var amountInCents = Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100);
  var displayAmount = parseFloat(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  // Open Checkout with further options
  handler.open({
    name: 'Demo Site',
    description: 'Custom amount ($' + displayAmount + ')',
    amount: amountInCents,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add my charge.php file in the form action field.